# Does there exist a function whose graph contains any finite collection of points in the plane, no two with the same x coordinates, up to translation?

Tags: functions

Given any finite set of points in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, no two with the same $x$-coordinates, it is easy to find a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ whose graph passes through all of them. In fact, Lagrange interpolation tells us functions as nice as polynomials will do the job. Can we do it with just one function?

The obvious answer is no, since if $f(x)=y$ then any set of points containing $(x,y)$, $z\neq y$, will never be covered by $f$. But what if we are allowed to translate this function not only horizontally but also vertically? Does there exist a function $f$ such that no matter what finite set of points we start with, some set of points in $f$ contains the "shape" of those finite points?

My first thought was that of the pathological solutions to the Cauchy functional equation $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$. But I don't know how to prove this does/doesn't work, and as a sort of bonus I'd prefer something which is more axiomatically efficient (this certainly doesn't look like a problem requiring even all of $\sf{ZF}$).

I have a suspicion the answer may be no, however. My reasoning, intuitively, is that there are uncountably infinitely many sets of finite points, even up to translation. Each collection of (at least $2$) finite points has nonzero width. From here I wish to use an argument similar to that which states every collection of pair-wise disjoint intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ is countable, where we note that even if we were to try and go "finite set by finite set" and fit the function to one finite set, then to the next, and so on, we would only cover countably many finite sets (since $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$ is dense and countable). Of course the issue here is that the function may satisfy many finite sets in the same interval, and in fact we can have uncountably infinitely many finite sets satisfied in any given interval.

I would not be surprised if this were possible. I would be somewhat surprised, however, if it were still true should we add certain smoothness conditions on the function. Perhaps differentiability, or infinite differentiability. Or maybe just continuity. To prevent the question from becoming too broad, I'll simply ask: Is it possible with no restrictions on $f$? Is it still possible if $f$ is continuous?

Comment: With no restrictions on $f$ it should be easy, even for countably infinite sets of points. Because there are just $2^{\aleph_0}$ such point sets, and as long as you've placed fewer than $2^{\aleph_0}$ of them, there's always room for the next one. Of course we need the axiom of choice so we can well-order the collection of point sets (countable partial functions).

Comment: @bof You're correct! I was too close-minded when considering "no conditions on $f$".

Comment: If a continuous function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ contains translates of all $3$-point functions, then for $0\lt a\lt b$ the mapping $$x\mapsto(f(x+a)-f(x),f(x+b)-f(x))$$ is a space-filling curve, so $f$ and even the difference function  $x\mapsto f(x+a)-f(x)$ are nondifferentiable.

Comment: By a "$3$-point function" I meant a set of three points in the plane, no two of which lie on a vertical line. A name I just made up but I thought it was fairly intuitive.

Comment: @bof Gotcha. It made sense once I put it into context with the rest of the comment.

Comment: @bof Hmm, actually, I'm not sure how you concluded a space-filling curve is nondifferentiable. Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: I don't mean nowhere differentiable, I just mean it can't be everywhere differentiable. I don't know the proof but I read it on Wikipedia so it must be true. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve#Properties

Answer (score -1):

For real $(a,b,c)$ the simple example of a parabola with symmetry axis parallel to $x-$ axis:

$$y= a+\sqrt{ b x +c}$$

Comment: Isn't any function of the form $a+\sqrt{bx+c}$ ($b\neq0$) monotonic? This wouldn't fit any set of points which is not monotonic then, right?